# Python prints Arabic text that includes punctuation incorrectly although it seems to be correctly stored

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-cleaning, arabic

There is strange behavior on printing Arabic text that includes punctuation in Python.

Example:

```
word_1 = "...واحد"
word_2 = "اثنان"
word_list = [word_1, word_2]
print(word_list)
```

The output of the previous code is `['...واحد', 'اثنان']` but the correct output should be `['واحد...', 'اثنان']`. This problem seems to exist only when I print the output. However, when I retrieve the first index I see the correct form. So the output of `word_list[0]` is `...واحد` which is correct.

The problem is that I want to print something to the user at the end so I want to print the output correctly. Therefore, I want the output to be `['واحد...', 'اثنان']`.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would the order of the list be reversed? Arabic is a RTL language, but lists containing strings aren't bidi.

Comment: Maybe because Arabic is written from right to left which is unlike the English language. @erip

Comment: So what would you expect if the list was `["...واحد", "Hello, world!"]`? String objects have bidi marks, but lists don't. If you want this behavior, you could create your own list with a custom `__repr__`.

Comment: The [python-bidi](https://github.com/MeirKriheli/python-bidi) library is generally used to display text from right to left. (Generally used with [python-arabic-reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper))

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eng. @erip. But how could I create my own list with a custom `__repr__`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eng. @ygorg. I have tried this
`reshaped_word_list = [arabic_reshaper.reshape(word) for word in word_list]`
, but the output is still printed incorrectly as the output I showed in my question.

Comment: If you wish to display a list is reverse order you can do `my_list[::-1]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eng. @ygorg. I tried this `word_list[::-1]` but the output became `['اثنان', '...واحد']` and not `['واحد...', 'اثنان']`. Well, it came closer to my desired output but not exactly as I want. Since I am first preprocessing the input text, I want the output to appear exactly as it appeared in the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because python is printing Left-to-Right
If you copy your output and paste in a Right-to-Left environment you will see this is right (For example paste in Notepad and press Right-CTRL+Right-Shift to change notepad to Right to Left and you will see your output is without problem)
This is your IDE issue that is printing Arabic output Left-to-Right

Edit:
You are writing into excel and should change paragraph-direction to RTL with this code

```
workbook.add_format({'reading_order': 2})
```

you can set reading_order to 2 to change paragraph direction from LTR to RTL

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eng. @Salman. Actually, my final output is written to an Excel file. I am using `xlsxwriter`, and I have adjusted the output format to be in Arabic by using this code `workbook.add_format({'align': 'right', 'valign': 'top', 'text_wrap': True})` so you could notice the right alignment in that piece of code. However, the problem still exists. Maybe I need something more than the right alignment to ensure Excel's proper Arabic language handling.

Comment: Ok brother, you should edit paragraph-direction not align (alignment), with this workbook.add_format({'reading_order': 2}). you just changed alignment not paragraph-direction, if you want know more, please read my answer again, I edited it

Comment: Yes, it worked correctly Eng. @Salman. I really want to thank you so much.

So whenever I am writing any Arabic text to an Excel file using `xlsxwriter` should I use this `workbook.add_format({'reading_order': 2})` for rendering the text correctly in the output Excel file?

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much, Eng. @Salman Daryanavard.