# How do I align the display of non-aligning dataframe columns containing Arabic, Thai, CJK, etc Unicode characters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I have a dataframe containing some foreign Unicode characters, such as Arabic and Thai, that causes my dataframe's columns to be misaligned when viewed by a `print(df)` on the Terminal.

I've tried `pd.set_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width", True)`, but it's only  aligning the rows containing CJK characters and not the Arabic and Thai rows.

How do I properly align dataframe columns when they contain Arabic and Thai characters (or possibly other misaligning Unicode characters / languages) when viewed by a `print(df)`?

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

unicode_chars_list = ['我是一個蘋果', '麺作りは美味しいです', '나는 공원에서 걷고 뛰는 것을 좋아합니다', 'اكل البيتزا لذيذ جدا اريد المزيد.', 'มีจระเข้อยู่ในแม่น้ำ โปรดระวัง', 'Ευχαριστώ τους προγόνους μας.', 'Normal English sentence']
data = {
    'a':[2134,4,547,56,3,234,124],
    'language': ['Chinese', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Arabic', 'Thai', 'Greek', 'English'],
    'unicode_chars': unicode_chars_list,
    'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'c': ['I am a long string here', '2nd string I want this to be some length', '3rd string please', '4th', '5th very loooooong',' 6 be good to the dataframe', '7 the end']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataframe's columns are aligned when viewed without foreign Unicode characters.

```
print(df.loc[:,['a','language','b','c']])
#       a  language  b                                         c
# 0  2134   Chinese  1                   I am a long string here
# 1     4  Japanese  2  2nd string I want this to be some length
# 2   547    Korean  3                         3rd string please
# 3    56    Arabic  4                                       4th
# 4     3      Thai  5                        5th very loooooong
# 5   234     Greek  6                6 be good to the dataframe
# 6   124   English  7                                 7 the end
```

When viewing the whole dataframe, the dataframe's CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean), Arabic, and Thai columns are not aligned.

```
print(df)
#       a  language                      unicode_chars  b                                         c
# 0  2134   Chinese                             我是一個蘋果  1                   I am a long string here
# 1     4  Japanese                         麺作りは美味しいです  2  2nd string I want this to be some length
# 2   547    Korean             나는 공원에서 걷고 뛰는 것을 좋아합니다  3                         3rd string please
# 3    56    Arabic  اكل البيتزا لذيذ جدا اريد المزيد.  4                                       4th
# 4     3      Thai     มีจระเข้อยู่ในแม่น้ำ โปรดระวัง  5                        5th very loooooong
# 5   234     Greek      Ευχαριστώ τους προγόνους μας.  6                6 be good to the dataframe
# 6   124   English            Normal English sentence  7                                 7 the end
```

After applying `pd.set_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width", True)`, CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) rows are aligned, but not the Arabic and Thai rows.

```
pd.set_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width", True)
print(df)
# Run this yourself to see the output, pasting onto here doesn't give the dataframe's true display.
```

Here are the screenshots of what it looks like when I run the above in the Terminal:

[image: Misaligned columns in Terminal]

And when I run in Jupyter Lab:

[image: Misaligned columns in Jupyter Lab]

How do I align the dataframe's columns containing Arabic and Thai characters when viewing it with a `print(df)`? Is there a way?

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.2, using Python 3.11.2.

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSAXH.png) (`Python 3.11.2` on `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2673]`, `pd.__version__ 
'1.5.3'`)

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura 13.2, it doesn't align for me in Terminal, also I ran this in Jupyter Notebook just now, and the misalignment became (more) misaligned. I have attached both images here: [Terminal and Jupyter Lab misalignments](https://imgur.com/a/cxVEB7U). I'm scratching my head on why I'm getting misalignment. `Python 3.11.2`

Comment: What if you use `۔` (U+06D4,  *Arabic Full Stop*) instead of ``.` (U+002E,  *Full Stop*)` in your Arabic string as `'اكل البيتزا لذيذ جدا اريد المزيد۔'` in place of `'اكل البيتزا لذيذ جدا اريد المزيد.'`?  Please don't respond in a  comment; [edit] your question to improve your [mcve] instead.

Comment: If I use an Arabic Full Stop, the same misalignment seems to occur: [With Arabic full stop](https://imgur.com/a/ryF2uVP). I've updated my post with more info.

Comment: Possibly related: [Python prints Arabic text that includes punctuation incorrectly although it seems to be correctly stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059459/)? Nothing more to say as my terminal prints Arabic text with incorrect direction…

Comment: The misalignment also happens with data rows containing Thai characters (left-to-right script), it's very confusing.

Comment: A couple of informal rules:

1) multilingual, multiscript data will not really display correctly in a terminal, no terminal/console has ever got it 100% correct.
2) In Jupyter lab just do `df`, not `print(df)`. Jupyter has its own logic for displaying a dataframe, and it works well for multilingual data on macOS. `print` adds levels of complexity thats not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Ah thanks @Andj it displays wonderfully (so far) with `df` and not `print(df)` in JupyterLab on macOS.

Comment: @Aeronautix there are limitations, most notably with support for bidirectional text. If you use the example in your question, you will notice the punctuation in the Arabic string is being displayed at start of sentence instead of end.

Although there may be a possibility to use a styler object to add an isolation embedding to improve RTL display. I was intending at some point to write up a note on Persian localisation of the dataframe display, this might be an appropriate time to do that.